# Merge Java module dependencies resources into WAR using Maven

Tags: java, html, maven, war

I have a multiplatform project which has several language-specific profiles. The HTML-platform-specific module depends on an "assets-core" module and if "en" profile is enabled, an "assets-en" module resources should also be included into WAR.

Assembling WAR works just fine with an exception that if "assets-core" module contains file with the same file name as "assets-en", it is not overwritten by the file from "assets-en" module.

I tried to use maven-resource-plugin:

```
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/assets-en/src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
```

with

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-prod-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <overwrite>true</overwrite>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/assets-ar/src/main/resources</directory>
                  <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                  </includes>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

and <maven.resources.overwrite>true</maven.resources.overwrite> enabled as other threads suggests, but nothing worked.

maven-war-plugin overlays could also be the solution but I can't have resource module to be packaged with <type>war</type> because the same module is also included in Java project.

Here are the relevant parts of my pom.xmls:

asssets-core/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>assets-core</artifactId>
</project>
```

assets-en/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>assets-en</artifactId>
</project>
```

example-html/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>example-html</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>example-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>example-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>assets-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>en</id>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.example</groupId>
          <artifactId>assets-en</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to overwrite the files? Usually with internationalization you want to tag your files with the locale (e.g., `messages_en.properties`) and include them side-by-side.

Comment: Because the images are different depending on the language. And the language profile is selected at build-time. But that is not the point. You can imagine brand type or anything else instead of language profile.

Comment: Except in that case I'd imagine not having any defaults to overwrite.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not the case. The project is very complex with lot of build flavors and profiles and the question is just simplified example. Furhtermore, the assets directory trees merging is quite often use case, so I'd like to know how to handle it with Maven. I.e. using Gradle it can be done but it's kind of pain too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I finally have found a solution. You need to get rid of dependencies to modules and copy the resources using maven-resources-plugin:

example-html/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>example-html</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>example-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>example-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-assets-core</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/ExampleProject/</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/assets-core/src/main/resources/assets</directory>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>en</id>

      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-assets-en</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/ExampleProject/</outputDirectory>
                  <resources>
                    <resource>
                      <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/assets-en/src/main/resources/assets</directory>
                    </resource>
                  </resources>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```